# Passing FromArgb() as a parameter to a function

Tags: function, powershell, system.drawing.color

I have the following function:

```
Function Color-Cells {
    Param (
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $true,
            Valuefrompipeline = $true)]
        [String]$Range,
        [Parameter(
            Mandatory = $true)]
        [System.Drawing.Color]$Color
    )
    $Global:WorkSheet.range($Range).Interior.color = $Color
}#End Function
```

Which I can call like this:

```
Color-Cells -Range "A1" -Color LightBlue
```

Without any problems.

I would like to be able to call the function like this:

```
Color-Cells -Range "A1" -Color FromArgb(217,217,217)
```

to get more granular with the color selection of a cell, however when I do that, I get the following error:

```
Color-Cells : Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Color'. Cannot convert value 
"FromArgb(217,190,238)" to type "System.Drawing.Color". Error: "FromArgb(217 is not a valid value for Int32."
At line:70 char:32
+ Color-Cells -Range "A1" -Color "FromArgb(217,217,217)"
+                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Color-Cells], ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentTransformationError,Color-Cells
```

I have tried calling the function like this:

1. `"FromArgb(217,217,217)"`
2. `'FromArgb(217,217,217)'`
3. `` `"FromArgb(217,217,217)`" ``

And they all produce errors.  I'm not very familiar with .Net, so I'm not sure how to fix this.  My end goal is to create a function that can color a range of cells based on either the `[System.drawing.color]` known name or the RGB value.

Edit for clarity:

The TypeName is specific as the parameter type in the function.  When I call the function `Color-cells` the `-Color` parameter is the type `[System.Drawing.Color]`.  When I call the function using the static property (`Color-Cells -Color LightBlue` for example) , it works just find.  However, when I try to invoke a method (`Color-Cells -Color FromArgb(217,217,217)` for example), that's when I get the error message. Is there a way to pass just the method into the function?

Per Mike's answer I can success fully called the function like this:

```
Color-Cell -Range "A1" -Color $([System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(217,190,238))
```

However, I would like to call the function (using a method) without adding the `$()` around the command and without the `[System.Drawing.Color]::` like I can with just the properties (LightBlue for example).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call static methods, use `[TYPENAME]::MethodName(args)`.

So do to what you're wanting, use this:

```
[System.Drawing.Color]::FromArgb(217,217,217)
```

Comment: I had to wrap it in `$()` to let keep the error away.  Is there a way to pass just `FromArgb(217,217,217)` as a parameter, without needing the `[system.drawing.color]::` with a static method?  I can do it with a static property, but I haven't found a way to pass a static method yet.

Comment: I don't  know any way to access a static member (method or property) without specifying the typename.

Comment: The typename is specific as the parameter type in the function.  When I call the function `Color-cells` the `-Color` switch is the type `[System.Drawing.Color]`.  When I call the function using the static property, it works just find.  However, when I try to invoke a method, that's when I get the error message.  I'm going to update the question to clear it up.

Comment: I'm guessing that PowerShell is doing the type conversion from string ('LightBlue') to Color for you based on a type adapter.  For instance, you can do [System.Drawing.Color]'LightBlue' and get the same value.

Comment: My point is that I don't think it's using the static property, but rather converting a string to a color.

Comment: I see, I didn't realize that's what it was doing.  I'll keep trying, if nothing comes up as a solution to not needing the `[system.drawing.color]` in front, then I'll accept your answer.